# KeyError: 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS' when adding data to AWS mysql Database from Flask app

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I've used the following as a guide to deploy a flask app with an AWS mysql database: https://medium.com/@rodkey/deploying-a-flask-application-on-aws-a72daba6bb80

When trying to add data to the AWS mysql database (the line "*db.session.add(choice1)*" below) I'm getting a "**KeyError: 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'**"

I've got an **app.py** file that looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request
from application import db
from application import app
from application.models import Data


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/returnToIndex')
def returnToIndex():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/informedConsentPage')
def informedConsentPage():
    return render_template('informedConsent.html')

@app.route('/consentPageForm', methods=['POST'])
def consentPageForm():
    choice1 = request.form['choice1']
    try:
        db.session.add(choice1)
        print("choice1 was commited")
        db.session.commit()        
        db.session.close()
    except:
        db.session.rollback()

    return render_template('questions.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

I've got a **db_create.py** as follows which runs successfully within a virtual environment

```
from application import db
from application.models import Data

db.create_all()

print("DB created.")
```

My **config.py** file looks like this (sensitive information removed):

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://username:password@endpoint:portnum/dbname'

SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE = 3600


WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = True
SECRET_KEY = 'whatever'
```

Finally within a folder called application I have an ****init.py**** file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

And a **models.py** file as follows:

```
from application import db

class Data(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    notes = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True, unique=False)
    
    def __init__(self, notes):
        self.notes = notes

    def __repr__(self):
```

I've tried a number of fixes such as setting SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS to false as you can see above. I've also tried installing different versions of sqlalchemy as per other stack questions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False in the config file itself.
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session
while adding an object in app.py you need to add the data to the model and then call db.session.add().
for example within the try block:

```
choice1 = request.form.get('notes')
data = Data(choice1)
db.session.add(data)
db.session.commit()
```